# Выпадающий список с возможностью ввода своих значений

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

В winforms есть combobox с типом dropdown, там можно выбрать значение из выпадающего списка, а можно ввести свои значения. Подскажите пожалуйста есть ли что то такое же в asp.net mvc. Нагуглил mvc datalist: http://mvc-datalist.azurewebsites.net/ Но хотелось бы что то потривиальнее. Есть у mvc что нибудь родное без установки чего то дополнительного из nuget или только этот вариант?

Comment: А при чем тут MVC? Весь UI - это html/css/js и прочие приблуды.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ немного не правильно написал. Суть не изменилась. Хочу найти такой элемент если он есть.

Comment: Нет, штатного нету. Ищите сторонние пакеты, если вам подобное нужно или пишите сами. Вопрос не особо тематический для so - поиск готовых пакетов, библиотек, фреймворков.

Comment: @AK понял спасибо. PS. А вы помните вы откликнулись на мой вопрос по поводу подключения библиотек, вы не знаете как решить мою проблему? Я там просто в теме код расписал, но ответа вы пока не давали.

Comment: Без идей, что может быть не так с тем вопросом